# Is CREATE_DATE a pre-defined table column?

Tags: mysql

In this question does CREATE_DATE refer to a user defined column or a pre-defined mySQL column?  If it is user defined what is a good assumption on what type the column is?

> Select all records from table REPORTS that have a CREATE_DATE before
>   July 9th 2006 in newest - oldest order.

Comment: it is a user defined column of type `Date`

Comment: yeh, all caps gives you an idea that it is a predefined column or a function, but it is not an issue it is just naming technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CREATE_DATE` is not a pre-defined column name; it would have been defined as part of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Most likely, it is going to be a MySQL `DATETIME` type, though it could also be the simpler `DATE` type.  See [MySQL date types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) for more information.

The difference between the `DATETIME` and `DATE` types is that `DATETIME` (as its name implies) includes a timestamp as well as the date, while `DATE` stores only the date part.

Comment: why did they put it in all caps...i'm use to lower case for column names.

Comment: @ChrisAaker Column name casing conventions vary.  Around here on SO you'll mostly see lowercase column names for MySQL.  Other RDBMS may prefer uppercase column names.

Comment: This company uses mySQL...is it preference or is there a correct way?

Comment: In MS SQL Server you'll often see CamelCase column names.  In Oracle, I've encountered pretty much an equal split between all lower and all upper columns & tables.

Comment: @ChrisAaker There is no correct way.  It comes down to the convention established by an organization, no different from preferring tabs or spaces for code indentation or CamelCasing vs underscode_separated function names.

Comment: spaces are better as tabs can be rendered differently depending on encoding....or so I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM REPORTS WHERE CREATE_DATE < '2006-07-09' ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC
```